# Deleting a range of csv columns

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I am trying to create an importable module to delete a range of columns (specifically columns 73-177 in the file I am working with).I am attempting to edit this file i/o code that is written for removing a column based on the field name. I want to modify this code to delete columns 73-177 in a csv file. What do I need to do to accomplish this?

```
def removeColumns(num1, num2, inputFILE, FileName):
    inPUTfile = open(inputFILE, 'r')
    outPUTfile = open(FileName, 'w')
    line = inPUTfile.readline()
    while line:
            # Delete Specified columns. First column range number, second column range number (+1)
            lineList = line.split('\t')
            removeCOL = "Calendar-Year"
            i = 0
            while lineList[i] != removeCOL:  #(linesout?):
                i = i + 1
            lineList.pop(i) #remove these fields from the list.append
            #write modified fields
            remove = "\t".join(lineList)
            outPUTfile.write(line) #write the new field names outfile
            for line in inPUTfile:  #remove field i from each remaining line and write it in the output file  &modify input line
                lineList = line.split( ) #convert to a list
                lineList.pop(i) #remove fields from the list
                line = '\t'.join(lineList)
                line = line + '\n' #add a carriage return to the end of the row
                outPUTfile.write(line)# Write the modified line in the output file
            inPUTfile.close() #close the input file
            outPUTfile.close() #close the output file
    return outPUTfile
    print outPUTfile
```

Answer (score 4):

I realize that you asked how to modify the original code, but here I honestly think it'd be easier to understand how to do it a different way.  Python has a useful [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module which handles a lot of the work for you.  Something like:

```
import csv

remove_from = 2
remove_to = 5

with open("to_delete.csv", "rb") as fp_in, open("newfile.csv", "wb") as fp_out:
    reader = csv.reader(fp_in, delimiter="\t")
    writer = csv.writer(fp_out, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        del row[remove_from:remove_to]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

will turn

```
$ cat to_delete.csv 
a   b   c   d   e   f   g
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
8   9   10  11  12  13  14
15  16  17  18  19  20  21
```

into

```
$ cat newfile.csv 
a   b   f   g
1   2   6   7
8   9   13  14
15  16  20  21
```

Comment: I attempted running that code and it unfortunately did not remove the columns. I am a beginner with python script writing, but the goal is to define a procedure that will remove a range of columns from any csv file

Comment: Then the first step is definitely understanding the `csv` module.  As demonstrated above, the code should work fine on tab-delimited csv files; it's trivial to turn it into a function.   What happened instead?  Did you get an error message?

Comment: no error message. it appeared to run just fine in python(using the code exactly as provided) but when I opened the new csv file to check it, the columns were still there.

Comment: Well, you must've changed at least the filenames, so you can't have used it *exactly* as provided.  Could you tell me what `print repr(open("youroriginalfilename.csv").readline())` gives?

Comment: By "youroriginalfilename.csv" I meant for you to put *your original filename* there, whatever it is.

Comment: if in input my original file name in it, it still just runs the script as before and returns a exit code of 0 while creating the new csv file.

Comment: it must have been thnking when I did than because now it just posted a list of all of the field names in the interactive window

Comment: I really needed to see what I asked for, the exact output of the `repr`, to confirm that the file was delimited as you think it was.

Comment: the entire output is "too long by 102529 characters" but this is the beginning: 'FireId,Organization,RegionState,RegionStateName,ReportingUnitId,ReportingUnitName,CalendarYear,FiscalYear,FireNumber,FireCode,FireName,FireType_ProtectionType,FireType,ProtectionType,CompletionCode,IndexTime,IndexTimeSource,SizeClass,LastModified,CauseCategory,Reimbursable,BurningIndex,Nrvc,Area,AreaName,Owner,OriginAccuracy,LocationMethod,CoordinateType,Datum,LatitudeDD,LongitudeDD,LatitudeDMS,LongitudeDMS,LatitudeEntered,LongitudeEntered,LatitudeNAD83,LongitudeNAD83,UtmZone,UtmEasting,UtmNorthing,

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the problem.  Your original code split on `\t`, assuming the data was tab-delimited.  My code, matching yours, set the delimiter to `\t`.  I said that my code would work on "tab-delimited csv files".  But that file is clearly separated by commas, and so is a "true" csv file (that's what the C stands for, after all :^).  Simply change `delimiter="\t"` to `delimiter=","`.